# File not found on _layouts/user.aspx? Any ideas why?

Tags: error, file

Does anyone have any idea what file may be missing?

[image]

//log

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file.
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.WebAdminPageBase.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.CBaseAclPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: sometimes, this has to do with your masterpage being faulty.

Comment: Please use the same server name (instead of localhost) with which you installed BP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to Disable/Enable the publishing feature:

```
PS C:\Users\spfarmadmin>Disable-spfeature Publishing -url http://yoursite/subsite -force

PS C:\Users\spfarmadmin> Enable-spfeature Publishing -url http://yoursite/subsite -force
```

Answer (score 1):

can you try copying the url and pasting it into an new tab, change the http to https. does it work?

If it works check out your alternate access mapping in the central admin.

if not than it is as stated by mike a masterpage issue

hope it helps :)